# Selenium Action chains - click multiple elements while holding a modifier key

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, vaadin

I have a scenario where I have to click on multiple `WebElement`s while holding a <kbd>CTRL</kbd> modifier key.

Selenium Actions generator looks like it was deigned exactly for that purpose so I built the following actions sequence:

```
@FindBy(css = "some_css_selector")
private List<WebElement> elements;

for (WebElement element : elements) {
    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);

    builder.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL)
        .click(element)
        .keyUp(Keys.CONTROL);

    Action selectMultiple = builder.build();

    selectMultiple.perform();
    }
```

So unfortunately that didn't work for me. What it did is selected each element separately but not both together.

I tried other options as well with no luck:

1. Didn't use `.keyUp` at all
2. Define the elements manually one by one and then call the `.click` on each one of them while *theoretically* holding the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> button

   ```
   WebElement el1 = elements.get(0);
   WebElement el2 = elements.get(1);

   Actions builder = new Actions(driver);


   builder.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL)
       .click(el1)
       .click(el2)
       .keyDown(Keys.CONTROL); //tried with and without

   Action selected = builder.build();
   selected.perform();
   ```
3. Use separate builders for each element

Am I missing some trick here?

**P.S.** I am using Firefox which should support the `Actions` class as it says on the official Selenium website.

**EDIT1** The elements I am trying to click are Vaadin generated grid cells.

Comment: You want to click on both elements at the same time or what

Comment: @Madhan no, I want to click on each element in list one by one while holding the CTRL button.

Comment: Is it possible to provide the link to the webpage

Comment: What is the type of Element you want to ctrl click checkboxes/ radiobuttons/links

Comment: These are Vaadin generated grid cell elements. Not sure that's a 100% correct description though.

Answer (score 1):

As you've said that you are using Vaadin grid Cell elements from the comment

I've automated a [simple flow](http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#ui/grids-and-trees/table) to select the table contents.The selenium click is not working on this. As a workaround I'm changing the classNames to select the cells.Appending `v-selected` to className do the trick

```
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#ui/grids-and-trees/table");
    List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tr[starts-with(@class,'v-table-row')]"));
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    for (WebElement element : elements) {
        if (element.isDisplayed()) {
            js.executeScript("arguments[0].className=arguments[0].className+' v-selected';", element);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. But how is this different from the approach I described in my question?

Comment: @EugeneS The builder is outside forloop

Comment: Yes, I see that. But I don't think it ,matters. I think that that's the execution phase which is problematic.

Comment: Yes I've tested your code also and it works fine as well.Maybe due to application behaviour

Comment: Yeah, I start to think that this might be the reason unfortunately.

Comment: @EugeneS I've added an alternate approach Check it

Comment: Thanks for that! I will check it and reply with a result.